# Call view function from subview with BackboneJS

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'd like to know if it's possible to call a view function from a subview with BackboneJS.
If yes, how it's working?

I want to call the function "hello" which belong to the mainView from the subview.

Maybe if event triggering...

Example:

```
var MainView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function() {
        this.$template = $(template);
        this.subview = new SubView();               
        this.render();              
    },

    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.$template);
        var element = this.$template.attr('id');
        this.subview.setElement('#'+element).render();
    },

    hello: function() {
        alert('Hello');
    }

});


var SubView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function() {
        this.$template = $(template);           
        this.render();              
    },

    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.$template);
        //Call view function ' hello '
        //parentView.hello();
    }

});
```

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried extending your `MainView` with `var SubView = Backbone.MainView.extend`? That should allow you to call the `hello` function from within `SubView`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pass a reference from your parent view to your subview:

http://jsfiddle.net/puleos/hecNz/

```
var MainView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function() {
        this.$template = $("<span>foo</span>");
        this.subview = new SubView({parent: this});               
        this.render();              
    },

    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.$template);
        var element = this.$template.attr('id');
        this.subview.setElement('#'+element).render();
    },

    hello: function() {
        alert('Hello');
    }

});


var SubView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function(options) {
        this.$template = $("<span>bar</span>");
        this.parent = options.parent;
        this.render();              
    },

    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.$template);
        this.parent.hello();
    }

});

var mainView = new MainView();

console.log(mainView);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try extending the `MainView` like this:

`var SubView = MainView.extend({ });`

That should then give you a reference to the `hello` function within `MainView`.

Or, in `SubView`, add this to your `render` function:

```
MainView.prototype.hello.call(this)
```

That would call the `hello` function in `MainView` using the context (template, other vars, etc) of the `SubView` instance.

Comment: This works but it is calling hello as a static method.  It would not be able to access the state of the MainView instance that created the SubView.

Comment: does he even want to access the state of the parent view?

Comment: Not sure but at least now he knows when to use the reference / options method vs. a static call.