# Pass Options from CollectionView to Recursive CompositeView

Tags: javascript, marionette, backbone-views

I'm doing something extremely similar to the tree structure described in this article:

http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/04/05/composite-views-tree-structures-tables-and-more/

The idea is to have a collection of root nodes in a collection view (TreeRoot) where each root node also has a recursive composite view (TreeView). A jsFiddle showing the simplest working example for a tree structure from the aricle can be found here:

http://jsfiddle.net/hoffmanc/NH9J6/

I want to modify the example so that some options can be passed to each tree view, regardless of where it is in the tree structure. Here is my (only very slightly modified) jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/QL4AE/1/

The JS code in my modified example is:

```
// The recursive tree view
var TreeView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    template: "#node-template",

    tagName: "li",

    initialize: function(){
        // grab the child collection from the parent model
        // so that we can render the collection as children
        // of this parent node
        this.collection = this.model.nodes;
        console.log(this.options.msg); // undefined!
    },

    appendHtml: function(cv, iv){
        cv.$("ul:first").append(iv.el);
    },
    onRender: function() {
        if(_.isUndefined(this.collection)){
            this.$("ul:first").remove();
        }
    }
});

// The tree's root: a simple collection view that renders 
// a recursive tree structure for each item in the collection
var TreeRoot = Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
    tagName: "ul",
    itemView: TreeView
});



// ----------------------------------------------------------------
// Below this line is normal stuff... models, templates, data, etc.
// ----------------------------------------------------------------
treeData = [
  {
    nodeName: "top level 1",
    nodes: [
      {
        nodeName: "2nd level, item 1",
        nodes: [
          { nodeName: "3rd level, item 1" },
          { nodeName: "3rd level, item 2" },
          { nodeName: "3rd level, item 3" }
        ]
      },
      {
        nodeName: "2nd level, item 2",
        nodes: [
          { nodeName: "3rd level, item 4" },
          { 
              nodeName: "3rd level, item 5",
              nodes: [
                  { nodeName: "4th level, item 1" },
                  { nodeName: "4th level, item 2" },
                  { nodeName: "4th level, item 3" }
              ]
          },
          { nodeName: "3rd level, item 6" }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    nodeName: "top level 2",
    nodes: [
      {
        nodeName: "2nd level, item 3",
        nodes: [
          { nodeName: "3rd level, item 7" },
          { nodeName: "3rd level, item 8" },
          { nodeName: "3rd level, item 9" }
        ]
      },
      {
        nodeName: "2nd level, item 4",
        nodes: [
          { nodeName: "3rd level, item 10" },
          { nodeName: "3rd level, item 11" },
          { nodeName: "3rd level, item 12" }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }

];


TreeNode = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        var nodes = this.get("nodes");
        if (nodes){
            this.nodes = new TreeNodeCollection(nodes);
            this.unset("nodes");
        }
    }        
});

TreeNodeCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: TreeNode
});

var tree = new TreeNodeCollection(treeData);
var treeView = new TreeRoot({
    collection: tree,
    itemViewOptions: {msg: 'hi'}
});
```

As you can see, I am attempting to pass options using itemViewOptions, but when TreeView is initialized, it is not there. I'm assuming that this is because only the TreeRoot is getting the itemViewOptions.

My question is: how do I pass options from the TreeRoot to the TreeView?

Thanks!

Comment: See my answer to this question.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/16427755/693799

Comment: Passing options is pretty straightforward using just Backbone, but I'm not sure how to do it specifically in this situation where there is a recursive composite view...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up going with a somewhat different implementation due to UI requirements (need to have tree inside a table). We are using a jQuery plugin called treetable to create a tree within a table. In the sample code below, the collection view is just a group of item views (the item views get appended directly to the DOM). Each node that has children creates a new collection view for them. The jQuery object that the ItemView el's need to be appended to is passed along to each ItemView.

**Javascript**:

```
var NodeView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    tagName: "tr",
    template: "#node-template",

    onRender: function() {

        var parent   = this.model;
        var children = parent.nodes;
        var table    = this.options.table;

        if (!table) {
            throw "No table element passed. Nowhere to append rows!";
        }

        table.append(this.el);

        if (children !== undefined) {
            // create and render new collection view for children nodes
            var childrenView = new TreeRoot({
                collection: children,
                parent: parent,
                table: table
            });
            childrenView.render();
        }
    }
});


var TreeRoot = Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
    itemView: NodeView,

    itemViewOptions: function() {
        return {
            table: this.options.table
        }
    },

    appendHtml: function(collectionView, itemView, index){

        /*
        * Set custom attributes needed by TreeTable jQuery plugin
        */

        var model = itemView.model;
        $(itemView.el).attr("data-tt-id", model.get("nodeName"));

        var parent = collectionView.options.parent;
        if (parent !== undefined) {
            $(itemView.el).attr("data-tt-parent-id", parent.get("nodeName"));
        }
    }

});



// ----------------------------------------------------------------
// Below this line is normal stuff... models, templates, data, etc.
// ----------------------------------------------------------------
treeData = [
  {
    nodeName: "top level 1",
    nodes: [
      {
        nodeName: "2nd level, item 1",
        nodes: [
          { nodeName: "3rd level, item 1" },
          { nodeName: "3rd level, item 2" },
          { nodeName: "3rd level, item 3" }
        ]
      },
      {
        nodeName: "2nd level, item 2",
        nodes: [
          { nodeName: "3rd level, item 4" },
          { 
              nodeName: "3rd level, item 5",
              nodes: [
                  { nodeName: "4th level, item 1" },
                  { nodeName: "4th level, item 2" },
                  { nodeName: "4th level, item 3" }
              ]
          },
          { nodeName: "3rd level, item 6" }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    nodeName: "top level 2",
    nodes: [
      {
        nodeName: "2nd level, item 3",
        nodes: [
          { nodeName: "3rd level, item 7" },
          { nodeName: "3rd level, item 8" },
          { nodeName: "3rd level, item 9" }
        ]
      },
      {
        nodeName: "2nd level, item 4",
        nodes: [
          { nodeName: "3rd level, item 10" },
          { nodeName: "3rd level, item 11" },
          { nodeName: "3rd level, item 12" }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }

];


TreeNode = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        var nodes = this.get("nodes");
        if (nodes){
            this.nodes = new TreeNodeCollection(nodes);
            this.unset("nodes");
        }
    }        
});

TreeNodeCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: TreeNode
});

var tree = new TreeNodeCollection(treeData);

var table = $('#tree');

var treeView = new TreeRoot({
    collection: tree,
    table: table
});

treeView.render();

table.treetable({ expandable: true });
```

**HTML**:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="https://raw.github.com/ludo/jquery-treetable/master/stylesheets/jquery.treetable.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://raw.github.com/ludo/jquery-treetable/master/stylesheets/jquery.treetable.theme.default.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://raw.github.com/documentcloud/underscore/master/underscore-min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://raw.github.com/documentcloud/backbone/master/backbone-min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://raw.github.com/derickbailey/backbone.marionette/master/lib/backbone.marionette.js"></script>
        <script src="https://raw.github.com/ludo/jquery-treetable/master/javascripts/src/jquery.treetable.js"></script>

        <script id="node-template" type="text/template">
            <td><%= nodeName %></td>
        </script>

        <table id="tree">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <script src="tree.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```